# How to load an ImageView from a png file?

Tags: android, file, load, png, imageview

I take a picture with the camera using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
startActivityForResult( intent, 22 );
```

When the activity completes, I write the bitmap picture out to a PNG file.

```
    java.io.FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("myfile.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
```

That goes OK, and I can see the file is created in my app private data space.

I'm having difficulty when I later want to display that image using an ImageView.

Can anyone suggest code to do this?

If I try to create a File with path separators in, it fails.
If I try to create a Uri from a name without separators, that fails.

I *can* open the file OK using:

```
        java.io.FileInputStream in = openFileInput("myfile.png");
```

But that doesn't give me the Uri I need to set an image with

```
   iv.setImageURI(u)
```

Summary: I have the picture in a png file in private app data.  What's the code to set that into an ImageView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` and then `setImageBitmap()` on the `ImageView`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that did it.

The only thing to watch is that you bmp.Compress it into a file, giving just the file name.

But to decode that same file, you have to construct and provide the entire pathname.  Android has several thoughtless asymmetries like this.
     String fname = c.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/myfile.png";
     Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fname);
     iv.setImageBitmap(bm);

Comment: To avoid OOM and "bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture" errors: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Works for me! Thank you very much! @CommonsWare Please, do you think you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/wO9G2N

Comment: What directory does the file need to be in?

Answer (score 8):

Also possible:

```
java.io.FileInputStream in = openFileInput("myfile.png");
iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
iv.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(in));
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer (in words) rather than just providing a single line of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not this way:

```
ImageView MyImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath( PATH TO FILE );
MyImageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference between `decodeStream()` and `decodeFile()`. `decodeFile()` method opens an inputstream and calls `decodeStream()`. This was already answered at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001439/setting-imageviews-image-from-filepath-bitmapfactory-decodefile-bitmapfactory)