# Setting ImageView's image from filepath. BitmapFactory.decodeFile, BitmapFactory.decodeStream or Drawable.fromFile?

Tags: java, android

Which is going to be the better (use less heap space) way for setting an ImageView's image?

```
    imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
```

or

```
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));
```

or

```
    is = new FileInputStream(path);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is));
    is.close();
```

The BitmapFactory will let me set an inSampleSize, so I don't pull too large a bitmap. Would the Drawable do anything like that for me?

Are there advantage to the BitmapFactory.decodeStream over BitmapFactory.decodeFile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should be no difference between `decodeStream()` and `decodeFile()`. In fact, `decodeFile()` does the same thing you do here. It opens an inputstream and calls `decodeStream()`. See [the source](http://google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/graphics/java/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java&q=BitmapFactory%20package:android&type=cs&l=279).

And [`Drawable.createFromPath()`](http://google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.java&q=Drawable%20package:android&type=cs&l=795) also just calls `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`. So it's in any case the same work/functionality.