# How to display python matplotlib graphs (png) with Chaquopy in Android Studio

Tags: android, python, matplotlib, chaquopy

So I use chaquopy to get simple python programs functioning in an old (jelly bean) tablet (I replace the example console app's main.py in the src directory). Not bad for a beginner's start and I'm very happy.

But now for a test I try to display a matplotlib graph like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
def main():

    image = mpimg.imread("/storage/emulated/0/Documents/test.png")
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

The matplotlib library was installed from within android studio (albeit with a few missing elements, manual pip3 install and usage of local files). Now the build and program finish without errors, but there is no graph. Installation of pillow and use of other graph types no avail.

Can this be handled in python, or is a dive into android studio / java required?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Installing matplotlib should be easy, so I'm concerned by "a few missing elements, manual pip3 install and usage of local files". If you had any problems here, please report them at the [Chaquopy GitHub page](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues).

Comment: I unfortunately do not have the logs anymore, but I remember that even after a manual pip3 install of matplotlib, it was still necessary to install freetype (a dev version was suggested). So I now have both libfreetype6 and libfreetype6-dev installed.

Comment: Chaquopy comes with its own copy of pip which installs into an isolated environment, so what you have installed on the build machine should make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to include an ImageView in your app's layout, and then load the image file into it, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2690030/220765).

For an image which is generated dynamically by matplotlib, either save it to a file and then load from that file, or save it to a bytes object like this:

```
import io
bio = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(bio, format="png")
b = bio.getvalue()
```

... and then load that bytes object into the ImageView like in [this app](https://github.com/Robbi-Blechdose/FT-TXT/blob/8751afe7fd0f74efb05f1635bb5b9a28d107013e/app/src/main/java/de/rbgs/ft_txt_app/Main.java#L264).

Comment: OK, I managed to show a png graph using imagegeview. Thank you very much. I did not test the bytes object yet, but it will also show just an image. What I now realize is that I wanted to make use of the matplotlib plt.show() function, because then the graph is not passively displayed, but shown with zoom/pan functions. Would that be possible?

Comment: @Peter: It's not currently possible: it would require someone to write an Android front end for matplotlib.