# Updating bitmap in ImageView with Chaquopy

Tags: android, python, matplotlib, chaquopy

I have been trying to graph data in Android using matplotlib through Chaquopy. So far, creating the plots themselves in Chaquopy has been very easy. However, I am unclear on exactly how to save the plot and load it into the ImageView. I looked at this example ([How to display python matplotlib graphs (png) with Chaquopy in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53285429/how-to-display-python-matplotlib-graphs-png-with-chaquopy-in-android-studio)), and that seems like a promising method, but it involves plotting in Python, storing the image as a bytes object, and then loading the bytes object into the ImageView in Java. Ideally, I would like to be able to do all of this, including updating the ImageView, from the python script. Is this possible?

Thanks for any help and advice!

Edit:
I found a solution that avoids the bytes object entirely:

```
root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
plt.savefig(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/fig1.png")
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/fig1.png")
self.findViewById(R.id.imageView).setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

If anyone has a solution using the bytes object though I would welcome any suggestions.