# Android ImageFormat size comparison

Tags: android, image-processing, image-compression, android-camerax, image-formats

Is there any comparison as to the size in memory or on disk of the various [ImageFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat) types available on Android?

I'm looking for the lowest size format (or alternatively the most compression) with little regard to image quality. I see the JPEG and HEIC formats are the only ones with the word "compressed" so I'd assume the lowest footprint would use one of these, but I'm not seeing any info that would allow me to compare these (or the potential other formats) with regard to memory size.

I was thinking to try generating one of each format and comparing, but I see no easy way to capture or convert to the vast majority of the types listed. For example, using the CameraX [ImageAnalysis](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/analyze) use case, it seems I can only get images in YUV_420_888 format. There are a few 3rd party or SO answers that could potentially convert to a few other formats, but I'm not seeing any easy way to compare these formats to compare the inherent sizes of each.

Comment: On Android 11: webp.

Comment: I think you are looking at the wrong class. Those formats are mostly for memory-internal representation. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat and you can load it this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688169/how-to-load-an-imageview-from-a-png-file

Comment: @Robert, thanks for the info. I was not aware of this difference until you mentioned it,  but I actually am interested in memory-internal representations as well (as I need to be working with a large number of images at a given time for my use-case). That being said, I also need to write them to a server later, so knowing what you provided also is helpful.